# Understanding SCH TDS2 in ITR1 (Indian Income Tax Filing)

Tags: income-tax, india

In the section titled "SCH TDS2" in "ITR1" form, there are two columns that I'm having a hard time with namely "Tax Deducted (5)" and "Amount out of (5) claimed this year (6)"  where (5) and (6) indicate the column value.

Can someone please tell me why these two columns are usually supposed to have the same values ? Also what do they signify ?

Answer (score 6):

> "Tax Deducted (5)" and "Amount out of (5) claimed this year (6)" where (5) and (6) indicate the column value

The Tax Deducted on Other Income can be for a previous year. Hence there are 2 columns, how much you are claiming this year.

For most individuals it would be same. So you can enter same amount in both columns.

**Edits**:
There are multiple scenarios where the tax is deducted in the current financial year but was due last year. Say a Property Deal, where the deal was signed in March, however the funds were transferred in April, hence the Buyer deducted the taxes in April and deposited with Income Tax. So in this case, if the tax is deducted of say 1000, you can claim that everything was for previous financial year, even though the tax was deducted this year. Like wise for TDS on interest where at times a financial institution would have deducted the taxes and deposited in the next financial year, it would also have deducted more taxes for the current year. In the ITR it would show a combined entry and you would have to based on Bank statement, allocate this appropriately.

Comment: Can you please explain what they mean with an example ? I'm still not able to understand. I'm filing my taxes for the first time